# How to target .Net 3.5 in Visual Studio 2012 Express?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2012 Express to target .Net 3.5? By default .Net 4.0 is targeted, but i couldn't change it. Is there a way to change this setting?

Thanks!

Comment: Multi-targeting isn't supported in the Express edition

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 Express and .NET 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153262/visual-studio-2012-express-and-net-2-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the template export option under the File menu in Visual Studio 2012 Express. I have used it to create project templates for targeting .net 3.5 and .net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Target framework is related to the project template not to the IDE and Since VS2012 doesn't have Export Template Wizard,I think you have to get a template project that targets .Net Framework 3.5 and create your projects with it.

 Hope it helps