# Visual Studio 2012 Express and .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio

My installation of VS 2012 Express doesn't show .NET Framework 2.0 when I create a new project. I know that 2.0 is supported on VS 2012 but it doesn't show up in the menu as shown below.

[image: New Project Screenshot]

When I create a project with one of the available options (4.0/4.5) and then change it back to 2.0, it gives loads of errors on build.

Is there any way to make VS 2012 to show older versions in the menu?

Comment: Are you using the Express Edition of Visual Studio? Normally you have a menupoint in the ComboBox to select more Framework versions

Comment: Hmm. What edition are you using? Mine shows a slew of options, plus a "More Frameworks" link at the bottom (Premium). Also, what OS are you on?

Comment: Are you sure that VStudio 2012 supports ***web*** projects for .NET 2?

Comment: Yes it supports 2.0. You can change it after you create project from menu : Debug -> Application Properties.

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer that worked for you, or to post your own answer explaining your solution. Future visitors will bless you for it.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you need to download the [targeting pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh454951.aspx) for 2.0. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/hh487283.aspx) lists the targeting packs available for VS 2012; it looks like it's just a matter of downloading the [.NET 3.5 SP1 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22) pack, which should then enable .NET 2, 3 and 3.5 targets.

EDIT: I've just noticed that you're using Express. I don't know whether targeting packs work the same way with the Express edition, but I'd at least give it a try.

Comment: I downloaded the .NET 3.5 SP1 Runtime package. When I run it, it tells me to activate 3.5 from "Turn Windows features On/Off" in Programs and features instead. It's already been activated there but still it doesn't work.

Comment: From the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/hh487283.aspx): *"On Windows 8, use "Turn Windows features on or off" to enable .NET Framework 3.5 runtime."*

Answer (score 5):

You can't set 2.0 (or anythign but 4.0 or 4.5) during the create operation, but you can change it after the project is created via the project properties.  This is true for VS express Web and VS express desktop (didn't try others).
[image: VS Express 2012 Target]

You will have to update your references to match appropriate targets.  Also various using statements, like System.Linq and System.Threading.Tasks need to be removed.

Obv MS is pushing 4.0 & 4.5 in their products, but support for old stuff is still there thankfully.

Answer (score 3):

The Express version of Visual Studio 2012 does only support the .NET Framework 4.0 and 4.5. If you want to develop applications targeting older version of the .NET Framework you have to choose an other Express versio of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Comment: But I think it supports 2.0. You can find the option under Debug -> Application Properties menu after you create a project.

Comment: this answer is inaccurate, you can do 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 in vs express 2012